# Temporary lock for rented accommodation

Tags: hotels, security, rental, homestay

I'm considering moving into a rented premises for a month or so. But the landlord's agent would keep a duplicate key of the door.

The landlord suggests that I should keep all valuables in the cupboard, to which my own lock can be affixed, because the agent might inspect the property at will.

I have some valuables which don't fit in the cupboard, but are liable to be stolen easily by a visitor.

So I'm looking for some help on any attachments or temporary locks for the main door, which can be affixed while leaving the house and would act as an additional lock, to prevent unauthorised entry.

Comment: Wouldn't this break your contract with the landlord? In theory you might as  well swap the locks.

Comment: I'm not sure of that

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't appear to be about travel.

Comment: A) this is not about travel, so you're asking on the wrong site B) this 100% depends on the country that you are renting the premises in, and you haven't stated the country - so the if it weren't off-topic, it still couldn't be answered meaningfully.

Comment: @DJClayworth Never rented a guesthouse during holiday/travel from which you make your daily tours? So why it is not travel-related?

Comment: Because the answer would be exactly the same if the place was in your home town rather than abroad.

Comment: I am amazed at the side tracked ranting on this question.  The OP asked a simple question about devices to secure a door of a temporary abode.  Rather than address the question, the majority of posters have attacked the OP using their hometown's laws as proof of the OP's unlawful intentions.  We don't know where this is taking place, therefore you DO NOT KNOW the applicable laws.  The "I know-it-all because my country does it that way" participants here are amazingly naive.

Comment: I can negotiate with owner to get permission for fixing my own additional lock temporarily

Comment: I am looking for something like https://www.nathosp.com/product/dqa100_c/hotel_room_door_locks_and_locksets

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure they are available in your area, but there are cylindrical covers that go over the door knob and are secured with a standard padlock.  With the cover in place you can't twist the knob nor access the keyhole.  The downside, it is pretty obvious when you aren't at home.

Comment: The other downside in this case is that if you deny the owner of the property legitimate access to it, they're completely entitled to cut the device off and bill you for the privilege. And throw you out of the accommodation for being in breach of your contract. So, you know...  don't do this.

Comment: That completely depends on the country. In many countries, luckily, it would be totally illegal for a landlord to enter a tenant house without the permission of the tenant, and in those countries the law does not allow a rental contract to contradict/supersede this. Since the OP hasn't stated country, it is not possible to meaningfully answer this quesiton.

Comment: @DavidRicherby - where I live, it is legal to do such. But ultimately the question is about devices, not the legality of doing so which varies from government to government..

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for device tips. I can negotiate the permission from the owner

Answer (score 11):

It is the norm for a landlord or his/her agent to have a key to an accommodation they own or rent. Landlord/tenant laws often include an access condition to the effect that they have to give the tenant advance notice before they enter. Were you to deny them access, locking them out by whatever means, you may violate your lease agreement. Depending upon circumstances, they may have the right to break through the new lock, charge you for that, decide that you are in violation, tell you to leave.

@SpehroPefhany makes a valuable observation:

> Usually there is an exception to the notice clause that in case of
>   emergency no notice is necessary. For example, if a pipe burst in the
>   tenants apartment and was causing damage to that and other units, the
>   landlord should be able to enter after a bit of reasonable knocking or
>   whatever.

Comment: Usually there is an exception to the notice clause that in case of emergency no notice is necessary. For example, if a pipe burst in the tenants apartment and was causing damage to that and other units, the landlord should be able to enter after a bit of reasonable knocking or whatever.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany you're absolutely correct and an important point +1; I will edit in your comment; it certainly adds value; thx.

Comment: "the norm" - maybe in some countries. Where I was raised, it was ILLEGAL to do that. It is trespassing for a landlord to access a tenant's accomodations without express permission. Legally enforcable.

Comment: @TomTom perhaps better said as 'uncommon' or 'unusual?' The statement is that it is normal for them to have a key, but not enter, though.